# rsync rename duplicated files in dest directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu, rsync, file-transfer

I have implemented a rsync based system to move files from different environments to others.

The problem I'm facing now is that sometimes, there are files with the same name, but different path and content.

I want to make rsync (if possible) rename duplicated files because I need and use `--no-relative` option.

Duplicated files can occur in two ways:

1. There was a file with same name in dest directory already.
2. In the same rsync execution, we are transferring file with same name in a different location. Ex: dir1/file.txt and dir2/file.txt

Adding `-b --suffix` options, allows me to have at least 1 repetition for the first duplicated file's type mentioned.

A minimum example (for Linux based systems):

```
mkdir sourceDir1 sourceDir2 sourceDir3 destDir;
echo "1" >> sourceDir1/file.txt;
echo "2" >> sourceDir2/file.txt;
echo "3" >> sourceDir3/file.txt;
rsync --no-relative sourceDir1/file.txt destDir
rsync --no-relative -b --suffix="_old" sourceDir2/file.txt sourceDir3/file.txt destDir
```

Is there any way to achieve my requirements?

Comment: The blazingly obvious solution is to get rid of `--no-relative`

Comment: @tripleee I also think so, but the requirement is clear _"I **need** and use `--no-relative` option"_, so I though of a work-around and posted it

Comment: Yep, It's a must requirement. The system create 1M files per day in a large hierarchical structure which must stay privately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can do it directly with `rsync`.

Here's a work-around in `bash` that does some preparation work with `find` and GNU `awk` and then calls `rsync` afterwards.

The idea is to categorize the input files by *"copy number"* (for example `sourceDir1/file.txt` would be the copy **#1** of `file.txt`, `sourceDir2/file.txt` the copy **#2** and `sourceDir3/file.txt` the copy **#3**) and generate a file per *"copy number"* containing the list of all the files in that category.

Then, you just have to launch an `rsync` with `--from-file` and a customized `--suffix` per category.

---

###### Pros

- fast: incomparable to firing one `rsync` per file.
- safe: it won't ever overwrite a file (see the step **#3** below).
- robust: handles any filename, even with newlines in it.

###### Cons

- the destination directory have to be empty (or else it might overwrite a few files).
- the code is a little long (and I made it longer by using a few [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)s and by splitting the `awk` call into two).

---

Here are the steps:

**0)**   Use a correct shebang for `bash` in your system.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

**1)**   Create a directory for storing the temporary files.

```bash
tmpdir=$( mktemp -d ) || exit 1
```

**2)**   Categorize the input files by *"duplicate number"*, generate the files for `rsync --from-file` (one per dup category), and get the total number of categories.

```bash
read filesCount < <(

    find sourceDir* -type f -print0 |

    LANG=C gawk -F '/' '
        BEGIN {
            RS = ORS = "\0"
            tmpdir = ARGV[2]
            delete ARGV[2]
        }
        {
            id = ++seen[$NF]
            if ( ! (id in outFiles) ) {
                outFilesCount++
                outFiles[id] = tmpdir "/" id
            }
            print $0 > outFiles[id]
        }
        END {
            printf "%d\n", outFilesCount
        }
    ' - "$tmpdir"
)
```

**3)**   Find a unique suffix — generated using a given set of chars — for `rsync --suffix` **=>** the string shall be **appended** to it.

<sub>**note:** You can skip this step if you know for sure that there's no existing filename that ends with `_old`+number.</sub>

```bash
(( filesCount > 0 )) && IFS='' read -r -d '' suffix < <(

    LANG=C gawk -F '/' '
        BEGIN {
            RS = ORS = "\0"
            charsCount = split( ARGV[2], chars)
            delete ARGV[2]
            for ( i = 1; i <= 255; i++ )
                ord[ sprintf( "%c", i ) ] = i
        }
        {
            l0 = length($NF)
            l1 = length(suffix)
            if  ( substr( $NF, l0 - l1, l1) == suffix ) {
                n = ord[ substr( $NF, l0 - l1 - 1, 1 ) ]
                suffix = chars[ (n + 1) % charsCount ] suffix
            }
        }
        END {
            print suffix
        }
    ' "$tmpdir/1" '0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/a/b/c/d/e/f'
)
```

**4)**   Run the `rsync`(s).

```bash
for (( i = filesCount; i > 0; i-- ))
do
    fromFile=$tmpdir/$i
    rsync --no-R -b --suffix="_old${i}_$suffix" -0 --files-from="$fromFile" ./ destDir/
done
```

**5)**   Clean-up the temporary directory.

```bash
rm -rf "$tmpdir"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is an amazing work/implementation/doc.

Comment: It's everything I wanted, I'm not used to work with bash nor awk and couldn't research properly to make this on my own...
I had to made some adaptations in order to merge it in my system.
Maybe I introduce a final step to remove the hash introduced in 3 step and recalculate duplicate id in each file

Answer (score 0):

Guess it's not possible with only rsync. You have to make a list of files first and analyze it to work around dupes. Take a look at this command:

```
$ rsync --no-implied-dirs --relative --dry-run --verbose sourceDir*/* dst/
sourceDir1/file.txt
sourceDir2/file.txt
sourceDir3/file.txt

sent 167 bytes  received 21 bytes  376.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6  speedup is 0.03 (DRY RUN)
```

Lets use it to create list of source files:

```
mapfile -t list < <(rsync --no-implied-dirs --relative --dry-run --verbose sourceDir*/* dst/)
```

Now we can loop through this list with something like this:

```
declare  -A count
for item in "${list[@]}"; {
    [[ $item =~ ^sent.*bytes/sec$ ]] && break
    [[ $item ]] || break
    fname=$(basename $item)
    echo "$item dst/$fname${count[$fname]}"
    ((count[$fname]++))
}

sourceDir1/file.txt dst/file.txt
sourceDir2/file.txt dst/file.txt1
sourceDir3/file.txt dst/file.txt2
```

Change echo to rsync and that is it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write an answer.
I can not use that implementation because it means one rsync per file and my system moves  large amounts of files so the performance would decay severely